# VB.net MYSQL - Count Seconds in Database between 2 times

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Hi im having a little problem with vb.net not sure which direction to head really.

The front end of the program is used to count seconds of a certain downtime of a process.

Database has the following table, and an example data:

- status | startdate           | stopdate             | Seconds

  ---
- Running  27/08/2012 11:10:11  27/08/2012 11:10:22       11
- Running  27/08/2012 11:10:11  27/08/2012 11:10:22       11
- Running  27/08/2012 12:14:27  27/08/2012 12:14:57       30

On the back end all im trying to do is populate a label with the sum of seconds using a datepicker for the date, and when doing the query i use the datepicker text and add the time on to the end of it, to no suprise it didnt work, also it only takes the start date into account, but not the stopdate as im trying to add up within that time frame, and im hopeing someone could help, this is the code i tried below:

```
Dim DTimePicker1 = DateTimePicker1.text & " 11:00:00"
        Dim DTimePicker2 = DateTimePicker1.text & " 12:00:00"

        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(seconds) FROM sqlccmlinestatus WHERE status = 'Running' and startdate BETWEEN @BEG AND @END"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEG", DTimePicker1)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END", DTimePicker1)
        Label70.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

Any help would be great.

Many Thanks,
Pete

Comment: if you want `"SELECT SUM(seconds)...` or BETWEEN to work, start by using numerics (long/int) as the dbcolumn and then store numerics not text; but SUMming a seconds of different records seems dubious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim D1 as Date = DateTimePicker1.Value
Dim D2 as Date = DateTimePicker2.Value
Dim DTimePicker1 as new Date(D1.Year, D1.Month, D1.Day, 11, 0, 0)
Dim DTimePicker2 as new Date(D2.Year, D2.Month, D2.Day, 12, 0, 0)
cmd.Parameters.Clear()
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(seconds) FROM sqlccmlinestatus WHERE status = 'Running' and startdate BETWEEN @BEG AND @END"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEG", DTimePicker1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END", DTimePicker2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"))
Label70.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, getting an error: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: I've made a change to the answer.